# Accessing IOptions and DbContext within ConfigureServices

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I've started to implement health checks in my .NET Core Web API. There are two health checks, one for checking if the SQL Server has any pending migrations and the other is checking if another API is live. Both added within `ConfigureServices` in `Startup` class.

In order to do the migration check, I need to access the `DbContext` which has already been added to DI using `AddDbContext` and to check the API, I need to get the API base url from configuration which is already in DI using `services.Configure<>`. I use the following code to get access to the `DbContext`.

I'm using `AspNetCore.HealthChecks.Uris` package to use `AddUrlGroup` health check.

```
var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var dbContext = sp.GetService<AppDbContext>();
var apis = sp.GetService<IOptions<InternalServicesConfiguration>>().Value;

services.AddHealthChecks().AddCheck("Database", new SqlDatabaseHealthCheck(dbContext), tags: new[] { "ready" })
            .AddUrlGroup(new Uri(new Uri(apis.Api1BaseUri), "/health/live"), HttpMethod.Get, "API 1", HealthStatus.UnHealthy, new []{"ready"});
```

But `services.BuildServiceProvider()` shows the following warning:

> Calling 'BuildServiceProvider' from application code results in an additional copy of singleton services being created. Consider alternatives such as dependency injecting services as parameters to 'Configure'

I can get the api base urls using

```
_configuration.GetSection("InternalServicesConfiguration").Get(typeof(InternalServicesConfiguration));
```

But I can't think of an alternative way to access the `DbContext`.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register your healthcheck like this:

```
services.AddHealthChecks()
    .AddCheck<ExampleHealthCheck>("Database");
```

And then just inject your `DbContext` into `ExampleHealthCheck` class, which has to implement `IHealthCheck` interface

Comment: Thanks @kebek, that worked. With regard to accessing `IOptions` (please see updated health check). Is there another way other than getting it using `_configuration.GetSection("").Get<>()` ?

Comment: I added another answer so its more clear, for this question

Answer (score 0):

There are some healthchecks you can use directly for EF in the official [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-3.1#entity-framework-core-dbcontext-probe)
But if you want to write any custom or more complex checks, your best bet might be to create a class that implements the `IHealthCheck` interface, where you can inject anything you want.

Also from the [docs about Custom health checks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-3.1#create-health-checks), an example:

```cs
public class ExampleHealthCheck : IHealthCheck
{
    public Task<HealthCheckResult> CheckHealthAsync(
        HealthCheckContext context,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var healthCheckResultHealthy = true;

        if (healthCheckResultHealthy)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(
                HealthCheckResult.Healthy("A healthy result."));
        }

        return Task.FromResult(
            HealthCheckResult.Unhealthy("An unhealthy result."));
    }
}
```

which, as kebek alerady answered, you will register like

```
services.AddHealthChecks()
    .AddCheck<ExampleHealthCheck>("example_health_check");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sotiris, I have setup the Database Health Check as above, but I was looking for how to inject DbContext into it without having to build the Service Provider.

Answer (score 0):

> With regard to accessing IOptions (please see updated health check). Is there another way other than getting it using _configuration.GetSection("").Get<>()

You could register those options in a following way (in ConfigureServices):

```
services.Configure<InternalServicesConfiguration>(Configuration.GetSection("InternalServicesConfiguration"));
```

And to get those options, in your class just inject `IOptions<InternalServicesConfiguration> options`, where the `options.Value` prop is the configuration value